# Java: Two backgrounds with same speed are overlapping each other

Tags: java, android, background-image

This is my first question and I'll try to make it as clear as possible. Please forgive me if someone asked a similar question before (I checked but found nothing).

I'm trying to create my first android application in java. It's a small game with a character on the left side of the screen (landscape mode) and a background which goes from right to left giving the impression of movement. The speed of the background is meant to be constant.
I used a Background class which looks like this:

```
public class Background {

    int x=0, y=0;
    Bitmap background;

    Background(int screenX, int screenY, Resources res){

        background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.background);
        background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, screenX, screenY, false);
    }
}
```

then in the GameView Class I create 2 background objects

```
private Background background1, background2;
```

and in the constructor:

```
background1 = new Background(screenX, screenY, getResources());
background2 = new Background(screenX, screenY, getResources());

//both backgrounds are the same picture

background2.x = screenX;

paint= new Paint();
```

finally:

```
private void update(){
    background1.x -=2 * screenRatioX;
    background2.x -=2 * screenRatioX;
    //both have the same speed

    if (background1.x + background1.background.getWidth()<0){
        background1.x = screenX;
        // to make it reappear on the right side when it vanishes on the left side
    }
    if (background2.x + background2.background.getWidth()<0){
        background2.x = screenX;
    }
}
```

I hope it's clear and that someone will be able to help me.

Comment: If I understand it right, the backgrounds are overlapping because both have initiated with same y coordinate value.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I don't understand, they both have the same y value because they are moving only in x (from left to right). They are not totally overlapping, only one is going faster so it starts overlapping the other one. Sorry English is not my mother tongue so I might have a poor word choice.

Comment: If you want to create mobile games is better to use a tool for game development, all the physics problem are solved and you focus on the game logic it self. Most of those tools have frienly IDEs so you can interact with your work and then later the games can be exported to mobile versions. I'll recommend you Construct2, is free, there is a pro version. Take a look and make sure it has the features you need.

Comment: Hey thank you for your suggestion, however I really enjoy learning java and I think it's more enjoyable to have a game I made from scratch, also because I would like to adapt games which are in other languages such as ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I actually solved it by giving background2 a x position relative to the position of background1

```
private void update(){
background1.x =(int)(background1.x - (2 * screenRatioX));
if(background1.x < background2.x) {
        background2.x = background1.x + background1.background.getWidth();}
        //(int)(background2.x - (2 * screenRatioX));
else {background2.x =background1.x-background1.background.getWidth();




    }

if (background1.x + background1.background.getWidth()<0){
    background1.x = background2.x + background2.background.getWidth();

}
if (background2.x + background2.background.getWidth()<0){
    background2.x = background1.x+background1.background.getWidth();
    }
```

I'm still interested in understanding  why this happened before. Thank you all